# How to format java shell output stream by removing illegal characters

Tags: java, shell

I have created shell session using Java. Using K I am entering commands and using '*in*' , '*channel*' I am obtaining the shell output. I am facing problems while fetching the shell output. As shown below output contains ascii value of few special characters.
Kindly let me know how to format the string Obtained.

I have given the sample output obtained.

**Output Obtained**:

> 1.68(B[m[39;49m[K Tasks:(B[m[39;49m(B[m 274 (B[m[39;49mtotal,(B[m[39;49m(B[m 1 (B[m[39;49mrunning..

The code I am using goes here:

```
public static void printOutput(InputStream in,Channel channel) {
String output= "";
try {

    byte[] tmp=new byte[1024];
    while(in.available()>0){
        int i=in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
        if(i<0){break;}
        output += new String(tmp, 0, i);
     }
    System.out.println("Inside print output");
    System.out.println(output);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e+"\n");
    e.printStackTrace();
} 

OutputStream os = channel.getOutputStream();
in = channel.getInputStream();
channel.connect();
os.write((command +"\n").getBytes());
os.flush();
printOutput(in,channel);
```

Comment: please add your outputs snapshot

Comment: Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code to see how ANSI escape sequences are constructed; then you'll know how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

replace all special characters to empty string

```
 output.replaceAll("[^\\w]", "");
```

below is the result.
if it isn't your except ,you can update the regex, choose characters that your want replace to empty stirng,for example:`[([;,.: ]`

```
168Bm3949mKTasksBm3949mBm274Bm3949mtotalBm3949mBm1Bm3949mrunning
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have found an alternate solution for it. A generic one. Writing this code after creating channel (ChannelShell)channel).setPtyType("dumb"); solves shell output issue.